# Why can't I color this SVG with the color CSS property

Tags: css, svg

I am looking for a way to change the color of an SVG icon (without `fill` since it's not supported on IE11) and I saw that Github does it using the `color` property.

I got this SVG from Github (basically the star button). If I go on Github and inspect it using developer tools and then set a color (`color: red`) on it, I can get it to change color.

However if I copy it on my page and try to do the same it does not work:

```css
.octicon-star {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<svg class="octicon octicon-star v-align-text-bottom" viewBox="0 0 14 16" version="1.1" width="14" height="16" aria-hidden="true"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14 6l-4.9-.64L7 1 4.9 5.36 0 6l3.6 3.26L2.67 14 7 11.67 11.33 14l-.93-4.74L14 6z"></path></svg>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: I am surprised that fill isn't support in IE11. are you sure? Is IE that bad ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif Haven't tried it but https://caniuse.com/#search=fill. Maybe I'm looking at the wrong thing..

Comment: That's something different altogether - fill works in ie

Comment: @Pete Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for `fill: CurrentColor`. It changes the `fill` of the svg according to the value of `color`. [Here's](https://css-tricks.com/cascading-svg-fill-color/) an article on CSS-Tricks on this.

Edit: Of course this uses `fill` aswell, but it's the method github is using.

```css
.octicon-star {
  color: green;
}

svg {
  fill: currentColor;
}
```

```html
<svg class="octicon octicon-star v-align-text-bottom" viewBox="0 0 14 16" version="1.1" width="14" height="16" aria-hidden="true"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14 6l-4.9-.64L7 1 4.9 5.36 0 6l3.6 3.26L2.67 14 7 11.67 11.33 14l-.93-4.74L14 6z"></path></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. Maybe it does work and this https://caniuse.com/#search=fill is talking about a different fill